# Enable to download CSV file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

Here i've a number of data which are fetched from database table. Now i want to download desired data as `csv` and ask to user for download that `csv` file.

my `csv` file was created but main issue the, it won't be ask to user for download that file.

**Here is my `AJAX` code which is executes when export button clicked**

```
$.ajax({
     url:"<?php echo site_url('Customer/ExportCsv'); ?>",
     type: 'post',
     data: { userId: userId },
     success:function(data){
        alert(data);
     }
});
```

**And here my controller function**

```
public function ExportCsv(){     
    $csvdata=array('customer_name','customer_email', 'customer_mobile','birth_date', 'marriage_date','address','status');//Column headers        
    // fetch the data
    $query = $this->db->get_where('customer', array('user_id' => $_POST['userId'],'is_deleted' => '0'));
    //$this->db->order_by("create_date", "desc");
    $getRes = $query->result_array();

    $csv = "ID,Customer Name,SenderId,UserID,Receiver Number,ReceiverID,Message Content,Send Date,Status,Message Length,Message Type,RequestID,FailureMsg \n";//Column headers

    foreach ($getRes as $record){
        $csv.= $record['customer_name'].','.$record['customer_email'].','.$record['customer_mobile'].','.$record['birth_date'].','.$record['anniversery_date'].','.$record['address'].','.$record['status']."\n"; //Append data to csv
    }

// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Yourdata.csv');

    $csv_handler = fopen('php://output', 'w');            
    fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv); //Write headers and data
    fclose ($csv_handler);  //Close CSV file connections
}
```

Please guide where am i going wrong..!  Thanks

Comment: what error r u getting? press f12 and check

Comment: it just print all csv data in console, but i want to ask for download csv file

Comment: why u r using ajax instead of ajax u can directly call page which u required

Comment: is their any way to do with AJAX?

Comment: ok, i've solved myself. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Just a lil change in my AJAX, and it works :)

```
$.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url('Customer/ExportCsv'); ?>",
            type: 'post',
            data: { userId: userId },
            success:function(data){
                $('#ExpCsv').attr('Disabled',false);
                $('#ExpCsvLoad').removeClass('fa fa-refresh fa-spin');
                $('#ExpCsvLoad').addClass('fa fa-cloud-download');
                $('#ExpCsvStatus').text('Export Customer CSV');

                // newly appended code line
                document.location.href = '<?php echo site_url('Customer/ExportCsv'); ?>';
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

Step 1:

```
$header_name=array('customer_name','customer_email','customer_mobile','birth_date','marriage_date','address','status');//Column headers

// fetch the data
    $query = $this->db->get_where('customer', array('user_id' => $_POST['userId'],'is_deleted' => '0'));
    $getRes = $query->result_array();
```

Step 2:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.csv");
```

Step 3:

```
// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output,$header_name);

// loop over the rows, outputting them
$finalData = array();

$fp = fopen('file.csv','w');
```

Step 4:

```
foreach( $getRes as  $data)
{

    $finalData[]=$data['customer_name'];
    $finalData[]=$data['customer_email'];
    $finalData[]=$data['customer_mobile'];
    $finalData[]=$data['birth_date'];
    $finalData[]=$data['marriage_date'];
    $finalData[]=$data['address'];
    $finalData[]=$data['status'];

    fputcsv($output, $finalData);
    unset($finalData);
}
```

Step 5:

```
fclose($fp);
```